# App crash on opening document for some devices

Tags: android

App crashes while opening csv file for few devices... all devices running same android version

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+File.separator +filename+".csv");
        Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"text/csv");
        target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        Intent icsv = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
        try {
            startActivity(icsv);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
            Toast.makeText(this, "get a csv reader", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Log cat

```
        at com.amra.Home.generateCsv(Home.java:581)
        at com.amra.Home.funExport(Home.java:185)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6367) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25032) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
2019-05-14 18:31:59.905 4096-4096/com.amra W/OPDiagnose: getService:OPDiagnoseService NULL
2019-05-14 18:31:59.910 4096-4192/com.amra D/OSTracker: OS Event: crash
2019-05-14 18:31:59.937 4096-4192/com.amra D/AbstractTracker: Event success
```

line 581 is

```
startActivity(icsv);
```

Comment: add the full stack from the log cat.. what error/exception did you get?

Comment: Also note that `Uri.fromFile()` will not work on Android 7.0+ -- use `FileProvider` to make your content available to other apps.

Comment: what is the equivalent of Uri.fromFile(file) while using FileProvider?

Comment: `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`, though you need to configure `FileProvider` first. See [the JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider).

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you're trying to open a file from within app best practice is to surround your open intent code with build version checks.
Please refer this below example and edit it as per your requirements this should surely fix it.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", toInstall);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(apkUri);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(toInstall);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "*/*");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Comment: getting an error for Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);

Comment: don't copy full code replace my uri line of code with yours

Comment: -_- ... i missed the "FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION" while creating intent.. fixed it tnx